# Hyper-V Mixed SQL server

Tags: performance, hyper-v, sql, rdp

I'm looking to setup a new SQL server. This is obviously a rather large expense so I was hoping to offset some of the cost by visualizing the machine and putting some other tasks on that same piece of hardware.

My question is this:
If I were to stand up a single piece of hardware (something robust, like a Poweredge R740, 128g-256g RAM, Dual CPU, SSDs), what would be the best way to configure disks/vhds so that I could run a base system of Server/Hyper-V, then have a VM with SQL 2017 in one VM, and something else rather robust like a Terminal server in another VM?

I obviously don't want users of the RDP to have any effect on the SQL transactions. Should I do something to split up the disks physically? Or just load it all up into a big array and use Hyper-V to handle it with VHDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I do something to split up the disks physically?

No

> Or just load it all up into a big array and use Hyper-V to handle it
>   with VHDs?

Yes

Comment: That's rather what my initial plan was. Just thought I would get some opinions.